# Check hash and then do a certain function

Tags: bash, script

I am trying to check a hash (doesn't matter which), and if a certain hash is met, then run certain commands.

Currently my code is

```
if [[ md5sum $file -ne $sum ]]
  then
    $commands
fi
```

However, bash refuses to run this, saying there are too many commands. How do I go about getting bash to run this simple if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error.

How about something like this?

```
file="file.txt"
sum="6f39af52b421a267040f88ba4bab95f4"
filesum=$(md5sum "$file" | cut -d" " -f1) 
if [[ "$sum" != "$filesum" ]]
  then
    echo They are different!
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. To put this in the wild, I am horrendous with bash. I am trying to clone a repo with git, but only if something has changed. You can view my full script here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d521a9582543fad4f07     However, this always results in chaos. Could you please correct my mistake somewhere in there.

Comment: @CTech Is it working now?

Comment: @CTech Can't you just `git pull` to get the latest version of the repo?

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this is if a file is changed locally, then not added, we will have a slight issue. I will have several friends working on this with me, and not all of them are comfortable with using git.

Comment: how about git pull --rebase? It will bring the latest changes from the server and put your at the end of those.

Comment: No matter what I do with pull I get From https://github.com/7CTech/PiCluster
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
 LICENSE
 README.md
 index.html
 pages/pages.html
 pages/what/what.html
 stylesheet.css
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: Well, I just nuked the directory, and re-wrote it, and it appears to be working now. I am going to do one more test then I will post back if success or failure!